# Datadog Agent check cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, python-2.7, datadog

I have written a Datadog Agent check in Python following the instructions on this page: https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/agent_checks/.

The agent check is supposed to read all files in a specified network folder and then send certain metrics to Datadog.

The folder to be read is specified like this in the Yaml file:

```
init_config:
taskResultLocation: "Z:/TaskResults"
```

This is the code used to read the folder, it is Python 2.7 because that is required by Datadog

```
task_result_location = self.init_config.get('taskResultLocation')
# Loop through all the XML files in the specified folder
for file in os.listdir(task_result_location):
```

If I just run the Python script in my IDE everything works correctly.
When the check is added to the Datadog Agent Manager on the same machine that the IDE is on and the check is run an error is thrown in the Datadog Agent Manager Log saying:

> 2018-08-14 14:33:26 EEST | ERROR | (runner.go:277 in work) | Error running check TaskResultErrorReader: [{"message": "[Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Z:/TaskResults/*.*'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"C:\Program Files\Datadog\Datadog Agent\embedded\lib\site-packages\datadog_checks\checks\base.py\", line 294, in run\n self.check(copy.deepcopy(self.instances[0]))\n File \"c:\programdata\datadog\checks.d\TaskResultErrorReader.py\", line 42, in check\n for file in os.listdir(task_result_location):\nWindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Z:/TaskResults/*.*'\n"}]

I have tried specifying the folder location in multiple ways with single and double quotes, forward and back slashes and double slashes but the same error is thrown.

Would anyone know if this is a Yaml syntax error or some sort of issue with Datadog or the Python?

Comment: After a lot of back and forth with Datadog support this is apparently a but which may be fixed in the future so there is no solution for this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to create a file share on the network drive and use that path instead of the full network drive path.
May be obvious to some but it didn't occur to me right away since the normal Python code worked without any issue outside of Datadog.

So instead of:

```
init_config:
taskResultLocation: "Z:/TaskResults"
```

use

```
init_config:
taskResultLocation: '//FileShareName/d/TaskResults'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though datadog is being run from the same machine, it is setting up a separate server on your machine. Because of that, it sounds like the datadog agent doesn't have access to your z:/ driver.

Try to put the "TaskResults" folder in your root directory (when running from datadog - where the mycheck.yaml file is) and change the path accordingly.

If this works and you still want to have a common drive to be able to share files from your computer to datadog's agent, you have to find a way to mount a drive\folder to the agent. They probably have a way to do that in the [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/)

Comment: Ah right, I didn't think of how Datadog was setting up. I'll give those idea a go but I can't change the folder location because it's part of another system. Thanks